# Why golang Lookup*** function can't provide a server parameter?

Tags: go, dns, nslookup

For `nslookup` command, it has `nslookup somewhere.com some.dns.server`.

However, it seems that golang dnsclient only load config from `/etc/resolv.conf`

code here: https://golang.org/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go#L225

Does the golang  standard  library provide something like 
`func LookupTXT(name string, dnsServer string) (txt []string, err error)` ?

`requirement`: 
1. Don't change the default `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: You can try this library instead: https://github.com/miekg/dns

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer   github.com/miekg/dns is too heavy for me.

Answer (score 33):

@holys

> "github.com/miekg/dns is too heavy for me"

It's not that heavy:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/miekg/dns"
)

func main() {

    target := "microsoft.com"
    server := "8.8.8.8"

    c := dns.Client{}
    m := dns.Msg{}
    m.SetQuestion(target+".", dns.TypeA)
    r, t, err := c.Exchange(&m, server+":53")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Took %v", t)
    if len(r.Answer) == 0 {
        log.Fatal("No results")
    }
    for _, ans := range r.Answer {
        Arecord := ans.(*dns.A)
        log.Printf("%s", Arecord.A)
    }
}
```

When run, you should see:

```
$ go run dns.go
2015/07/26 00:24:46 Took 16.138928ms
2015/07/26 00:24:46 134.170.188.221
2015/07/26 00:24:46 134.170.185.46
```

Comment: Thank you for the example application, that's very useful.

Answer (score 12):

@holys

You can use this simple [dns_resolver](http://github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver) based on miekg/dns

```
go get github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver"
)

func main() {
    resolver := dns_resolver.New([]string{"8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"})

    // In case of i/o timeout
    resolver.RetryTimes = 5

    ip, err := resolver.LookupHost("google.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    log.Println(ip)
    // Output [216.58.192.46]
}
```

Comment: OP said, "_github.com/miekg/dns is too heavy for me_" but this one, github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver, is built **on top of** miekg/dns, so it is adding another layer, not "_simple_" at all.

Answer (score 12):

[Since a little while](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19268#issuecomment-345384876) you can set the Dial for the Resolver, where you can define your nameserver in the DialContext

```golang
var resolver *net.Resolver

if nameserver != "" {
    resolver = &net.Resolver{
        PreferGo: true,
        Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
            d := net.Dialer{}
            return d.DialContext(ctx, "udp", net.JoinHostPort(nameserver, "53"))
        },
    }
} else {
    resolver = net.DefaultResolver
}
```

After that you can go as you're used to:

```
ips, err := resolver.LookupIPAddr(context.Background(), "www.example.com")
```

Comment: I noticed that this can't be used to bypass the hosts file. If you want to direct-query a DNS server from Go it seems that github.com/miekg/dns is the best bet (as described in other answers)

Comment: Not on Windows 10?

Comment: > I noticed that this can't be used to bypass the hosts file
@0x574F4F54 what's the source of this?

Answer (score 5):

Since Go 1.9 this is possible by overriding the `Dial` function on a [`Resolver`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Resolver). For example, to ignore the request for the local resolver over UDP and connect to `9.9.9.9` via TCP we might do something like this:

```golang
r := &net.Resolver{
    Dial: func(ctx context.Context, _, _ string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return net.Dial("tcp", "9.9.9.9")
    },
}
addrs, err := r.LookupIPAddr(context.TODO(), "example.net")
```

Answer (score 4):

The `net.Lookup*` functions provide access to the local resolver.  While many requests will be answered with information from a DNS server, this is not always the case.

For instance, `LookupHost` may return a name from the `/etc/hosts` file.  Or it might use mDNS to resolve a `.local` name.

If you want to talk to an arbitrary DNS server rather than the local resolver, then you should use a general purpose DNS client library.  As suggested in the comments, https://github.com/miekg/dns might fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for your advise.  I made a simple [wrapper](https://github.com/holys/nslookup) for `nslookup` command to suit my case.

Comment: If your concern was overhead, then shelling out to nslookup is likely to be more heavyweight than an in-process DNS library.