# App doesn't resolve an internal DNS entry when connecting via Cisco IPSec

Tags: go, dns, vpn

I use Cisco IPsec to connect to my workplace VPN. I connect using OS X's native Cisco IPSec client. We have an internal DNS server that holds records for internal sites, such as `scotty.infinidat.com`. Using curl to contact an internal site works as expected. Using the following Python code also works:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
resp.raise_for_status()

resp = requests.get("http://scotty.infinidat.com")
resp.raise_for_status()
```

However, trying to implement an equivalent in Go fails:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    _, err := http.Get("http://google.com/") // This works
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error contacting Google: %s", err))
    }

    _, err = http.Get("http://scotty.infinidat.com/") // This doesn't
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error contacting an internal site: %s", err))
    }
}
```

Running the program above while connected to the VPN yields the following output:

```
panic: Error contacting internal site: Get http://scotty.infinidat.com/: dial tcp: lookup scotty.infinidat.com on 10.135.1.1:53: no such host

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x290ca0, 0xc82010a490)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
main.main()
        /Users/roeyd/src/go/src/webtest/main.go:16 +0x2af
```

Where 10.135.1.1 is my local network's DNS server. To my understanding the pure Go DNS resolver isn't available on OS X. Forcing Go to use the cgo DNS resolver by setting `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: This thread might be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043248/why-golang-lookup-function-cant-provide-a-server-parameter

Comment: This seems like a bug, so you should file an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues), also try to compile go from git and see if the problem is fixed in it (there was some DNS work in git few days ago).

Comment: OSX uses cgo by default https://golang.org/src/net/conf.go#L68

Comment: This may be relevant: http://serverfault.com/questions/478534/how-is-dns-lookup-configured-for-osx-mountain-lion

Comment: Please provide the output of `host -a scotty.infinidat.com` from the OSX command line while connected to the VPN, and while disconnected.  (Assuming the behaviour is different whether connected or not)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a complete DNS library to first resolve the IP:

```
 package main

 import (
    "log"

    "github.com/miekg/dns"
 )

 func main() {
    c := dns.Client{}
    m := dns.Msg{}
    m.SetQuestion("scotty.infinidat.com.", dns.TypeA)
    r, t, err := c.Exchange(&m, "10.135.1.1:53")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Took %v", t)
    for _, ans := range r.Answer {
        Arecord := ans.(*dns.A)
        log.Printf("%s", Arecord.A)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already did this but from my side when executing `dig scotty.infinidat.com` I got no records (matching your results):

```
$ dig scotty.infinidat.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> scotty.infinidat.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 53313
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;scotty.infinidat.com.          IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
infinidat.com.          155     IN      SOA     ns1.dnsimple.com. admin.dnsimple.com. 1438782431 86400 7200 604800 300

;; Query time: 234 msec
;; SERVER: 10.132.0.1#53(10.132.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 30 21:37:14 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 93
```

So if for `www.google.com` is working, probably high are the changes is something more related to your DNS/ZONE.