# ask LookupTXT function in golang

Tags: windows, go, dns

How do I change the IP address of the DNS server?

In situation, I set Google DNS server in Windows Network Settins.

And I use `LookupTXT` function in Golang for getting DNS txt request.
But `LookupTXT` parameter is just the query string.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "On Windows, the resolver always uses C library functions, such as GetAddrInfo and DnsQuery." - [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution)

Answer (score 0):

This is not straigtforward to do using golang at this point. You can however use a third party DNS package that allows configuring the resolver. First install the package:

```
go get github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver
```

Here is an example using it and the google resolvers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver"
)

func main() {
    resolver := dns_resolver.New([]string{"8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"})

    // In case of i/o timeout
    resolver.RetryTimes = 5

    ip, err := resolver.LookupHost("google.com")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    log.Println(ip)
    // Output [216.58.192.46]
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32325270/1318734)

There is an open issue in golang here, so hopefully it becomes easier to do it with the builtin `net` package: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12503. It could just be a documentation problem, as it is possible now, I just can't find an example.

EDIT: actually that package only supports `lookupHost`: https://github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver/blob/master/dns_resolver.go#L51-L79

So a PR would be required to add a TXT resolver.

2nd Edit: I made a PR with txt lookup [here](https://github.com/bogdanovich/dns_resolver/pull/2). That project hasn't been touched in years though so it may never get accepted.